# Cannot call methods on varchar(max)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I tried to modify/update xml column of type `varchar(max)` in SQL Server.

But I'm getting this error:

> Cannot call methods on varchar(max)

This is my table structure and query:

```
CREATE TABLE #Sites
(
    [SiteID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SiteInfo] VARCHAR(MAX),
    [InVal] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [InVal1] VARCHAR(50) NULL
)

UPDATE #Sites 
SET [SiteInfo].modify('insert <SiteID/> into (/SiteInfo[1])')
```

Comment: Okay.  Use `XML` instead.  That's why it exists.

Comment: Why are you using `varchar(max)` instead of `xml` datatype?

Comment: Those **XML** methods work ..... only on the `XML` datatype, not very surprisingly .......

Comment: Thank you, but i need to update the table which i can't change the datatype and datatype is varchar(max)
I need to replace the xml element with new element@marc_s

Comment: This is why using the correct datatype is important, and why using the incorrect one is a bad idea. Imagine storing numbers as a `varchar` and then "adding" then together. `1 + 2` isn't `12`, it's 3; that's exactly what would happen with `'1'+'2'`. `varchar` is a far cry from a "one size fits all" datatype.

Comment: @VenkataJagadishPippalla but it's a temporary table, why can't you change the `CREATE` statement? (or is the fact that you used a temporary table an example)

Comment: @Larnu
actually, I'm modifying column in other table which had datatype varcharmax
and i dont have access to change datatype for it. I just loaded some xml data into it. Now i got some issues in on xml element and i need to replace the element with new value
for example :
<name>jagadish</name><state>NJ</state>
I need to replace state
<name>jagadish</name><state>CA</state>

Comment: Perhaps you should talk to someone that can? They *should* understand the implications of bad datatype choices.

Comment: As your column is not `XML`, you can't use `modify` -- `CAST` and `CONVERT` won't help you there either, although you could use those in combination with `.query()` to produce a new XML of the desired shape. I'm no FLWOR virtuoso, though.

Answer (score 3):

The only way you're going to be able to deal with this is to insert your data into an actual `xml` datatype in a (temporary) table, run an `UPDATE` on that and then `UPDATE` your original data. Provided that `SiteID` is **unique** then you can do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Sites (id int IDENTITY(1,1),
                     NotXML varchar(MAX))
INSERT INTO #Sites (NotXML)
VALUES ('<SiteInfo><name>jagadish</name><state>NJ</state></SiteInfo>')
GO
CREATE TABLE #XML (id int,
                   RealXML xml);
INSERT INTO #XML
SELECT id, TRY_CONVERT(xml,NotXML)
FROM #Sites
WHERE id = 1
  AND TRY_CONVERT(xml,NotXML) IS NOT NULL; --as we can't deal with bad XML

UPDATE #XML
SET [RealXML].modify('insert <SiteID/> into (/SiteInfo[1])');

UPDATE S
SET NotXML = CONVERT(varchar(MAX),X.RealXML)
FROM #Sites S
     JOIN #XML X ON S.id = X.id;

SELECT NotXML
FROM #Sites;    

DROP TABLE #XML;
GO
DROP TABLE #Sites;
```

This, however, is going to be less than performant, and won't be able to handle bad XML; if your `varchar(MAX)` contains invalid XML it will not be updated.